# Run Java Selenium webdriver program from batch file (Not for testing)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jsoup, opencsv

I am using Selenium WebDriver, Jsoup, Opencsv,  and Java to parse HTML pages including javascript of one website, and then generate csv file. I can run it from Eclipse but I want to automate it using batch file. My java program has two classes - main and website. So I copied those two classes that generated by Eclipse and put it in one folder. Then I also copied all the external jar files such as selenium 2.33.0, opencsv-2.3 and jsoup 1.7.2, and created batch file in the same folder as

@ECHO OFF
   Java Main
   pause

Then I tried to run batch file, but it failed. I tried again to change the batch file as

```
@ECHO OFF
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Data\Website\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-2.33.0\*.jar;C:\Data\Website\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-2.33.0\libs\*.jar
Java Main
pause
```

but still the same error produced as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/W
ebDriver
        at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 1 more
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Kindly help. I searched how to run Selenium webdriver tests from batch file but I found out that JUnit is needed. I just use Java, and third party libraries to get my requirements.
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is easy.

```
@ECHO off
SET "SELDIR=C:\Data\Website\selenium-2.33.0"
SET "CLASSPATH=.;%SELDIR%\*.jar;%SELDIR%\libs\*.jar"
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" MainClassName arg1 arg2
PAUSE
```

Comment: I tried your code but still got the same error from cmd. I can't also see org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver folders in that selenium-2.33.0 folder that was downloaded and extracted. But when I used Selenium Webdriver in Eclipse, I used as the following without those folders and sub folders and got no error in Eclipse.

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;